# runas xcopy crashing my Electron application

Tags: javascript, electron, clojurescript, runas

I'm trying to copy a scr file to c:\Windows\System32 using [runas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/runas) and xcopy and it's crashing my application. I'm writing in ClojureScript so my code looks like this:

```
(runas "C:\\Windows\\System32\\xcopy.exe"
       #js ["C:\\Users\\pupeno\\Documents\\Dashman\\clients\\dist\\win-unpacked\\Dashman.scr"
            "C:\\Windows\\System32\\"
            "/F"]                                                                                    
       #js {:admin true})
```

which compiles to:

```
configurator.main.runas.call(null,
                             "C:\\Windows\\System32\\xcopy.exe",
                             ["C:\\Users\\pupeno\\Documents\\Dashman\\clients\\dist\\win-unpacked\\Dashman.scr",
                              "C:\\Windows\\System32\\",
                              "/F"],
                             ({"admin": true}));
```

When I run this code, I get asked for the password but then the app just freezes. Any ideas what might be wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. xcopy was prompting for overwrite permission, adding /Y attribute solved that.

Also, surprisingly, I could never get any output from xcopy, regardless of setting catchOutput to true or not.